# Kibana: Subtracting 2 fields with different document

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

[I have this of data. (Click Me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhBeU.png)

I want to add the red marker then subtract it to the blue marker.
I tried using this [Scripted Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc9nO.png).

But when I go back to discovery I have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8UER.png).

If I will put it on the line graph I want to subtract the blue line from the green line to see the difference on the data.

[Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNjqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that between docs in that manner sorry

your best option would be to run a transform or rollup job, depending on what the data is like, to have a single doc that covers all 3 of the ones you have in your fist image